# Finding a certain object within JSON

Tags: sql, arrays, json, object, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to query if a specific column exists within a nested JSON structure. Is there a way to do this?
For example in the same JSON, I have some that include "favoriteNumber" within "Friends" and some that don't.

For example, these are the different cases we have:

```
{   "name": "Kyle",
    "favoriteNumber":3
    "isProgrammer":3,
    "hobbies":["weight Lifting","Bowling"],
    "friends":[{
     "name":"Joey",
     "favoriteNumber":100,
     "isProgrammer":false,
     "friends"[...]
}]
}
```

And some cases where there is no "favoriteNumber" within "Friends"

```
{   "name": "Travis",
    "favoriteNumber":3
    "isProgrammer":3,
    "hobbies":["Scuba Diving","Bowling"],
    "friends":[{
     "name":"Monica",
     "isProgrammer":false,
     "friends"[...]
}]
}
```

I want to find all the json that has the "favoriteNumber" within "friends". So in the examples above, only the first one should show. How can I do this? So I am looking if a specific object exists.

Comment: What language do you want to use to find the persons with no `favoriteNumber` key within `friends`? Also, what is in the nested array `"friends": [...]`? Do you want to find items that have no `favouriteKey` inside that too?

Comment: Yes! Basically find all the sections that have the FavoriteNumber within Friends ,and the nested array "friends" we can ignore that one.

Comment: And what programming language are you using for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a JSON object per row and you want to know if any friend has a favorite number. And we assume name is distinct within the data (so Kyle had three friends two of which have favorite numbers we only get one then this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.value:name::text as name, j.value as json
FROM data_table t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>t.json) j,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>j.value:friends) f
WHERE IS_INTEGER(f.value:favoriteNumber);
```

well the above code will unroll all people in the row's json (if it's an array) , so given your example where the top level json is not an array, the `j` flatten could be skipped like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.json:name::text as name, t.json as json
FROM data_table t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>t.json:friends) f,
WHERE IS_INTEGER(f.value:favoriteNumber);
```